# Block interactive SSH sessions while allowing certain commands

Tags: ssh

How would one only allow certain commands to be run via SSH and block interactive sessions?

rsync.net does this as well as bakop.com.

I.e. this would work:

```
ssh <user@host> mkdir test
scp <file> <user@host>:test/
```

And this would not:

```
ssh <user@host>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can take advantage of the ability to restrict the key to a particular command using the `command=` directive in authorized_keys and the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` variable that gets passed to the remote system.

In the authorized_keys file change the line containing the relevant key from

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc...
```

to

```
command="/path/to/myscript" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc...
```

Then create the myscript file like for example

```
#!/bin/bash

if [  ! -n "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ]
then
    echo "No command supplied"
    exit 1
fi


set $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND

case "$1" in
    ls)
      ;;
    md5)
      ;;
    *)
      echo "invalid command"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac

    exec "$@"
```

so now if you run `ssh user@remote.tld ls /etc` you'll get a listing of the remote `/etc` directory. You'll probably want to use the case statements to test the supplied parameters to meet whatever your implementation requirements are.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing your own shell from scratch, you might want to extend this:

https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki

It provides a shell you can set as a user (i.e. `usermod` or directly in `/etc/passwd`) which only supports SCP. You'll want to extend this to a few select binaries of your choice, of which none should be an interactive shell (e.g. `/bin/bash`, `/bin/sh`). More carefully, they shoudn't be able to upload one (e.g. a busybox binary) and set the executable bit so they can drop in their own shell.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different shell for that user - you may have to write your own if you have specific requirements, but you would need to take a lot of care! Many shells offer restricted operation already but they may not be restricted enough for you.

Scp can make directories though - so what else do you need to allow the user to do through interactive ssh?