# command parameter in .ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, remote, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [simple rsync in crontab without password](https://serverfault.com/questions/255084/simple-rsync-in-crontab-without-password)

I'm implementing remote backups using rsync. The backup server connects to the host containing the stuff to backup (serverX), using certificates. It works great.

But now I want to backup /etc/*, but it requires root permissions. So I changed ssh config to:
PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only

And then on /root/.ssh/authorized_keys I have:
from="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24",command="/usr/bin/rsync*",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3 (.....)

Then, from the backup server I use this command:
/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e ssh root@serverX:/etc localdir/etc

But it does not work because in serverX, it replaces all the command with "/usr/bin/rsync". So all the parameters are lost.

I tried using wildcards in the command clause in authorized_keys to: command="/usr/bin/rsync*" -- but it does not seem to work.

I do not want to specify the entire command in the command clause because I run rsync multiple times with different parameters. I tried putting all inside a bash script, but it got me even more confused, because it seems that it looks for the script in serverX, not in the backup server.

How can I used forced commands for root SSH logins and at the same time use different parameters for those forced commands ?

**Solution:**

I implemented a solution based on SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable:
I created a script in serverX that based on this variable, executes rsync to the backup server.

Now, instead of executing "rsync -avz -e ssh

I, just "ssh root@serverX commandX"

In ServerX I have authorized_keys like this:
from="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24",command="/root/bin/backup/myscript.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA (...)

And myscript.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -n "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ]; then
     echo "No command supplied"
     exit 1
fi

echo "-> $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"

set $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
case "$1" in
    command1)
    rsync -avz -e ssh /etc  $BACKUPSERVER_USER@$BACKUPSERVER_SERVER:$REMOTE_BACKUP_BASEDIR
    ;;
*)
    echo "invalid command"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: You can use the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND evnironment variable - take a look at this http://serverfault.com/questions/255084/simple-rsync-in-crontab-without-password/255132#255132 or http://serverfault.com/questions/397198/block-interactive-ssh-sessions-while-allowing-certain-commands/397211#397211

Comment: That worked perfectly!